# Eclipse RCP: Recent Files in Filemenu

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have developed an RCP application. I want show the recent files in File Menu of my eclipse RCP application.

Over google i found that i should use org.eclipse.ui.workbench.ContributionItemFactory.REOPEN_EDITORS.create(window) . But where? I am little lost. Help me out.

Regards,
Priyank

Answer (score 2):

Add a menu contribution: menu:file?after=additions
under that add dynmic.
Write a class which inherits from CompoundContributionItem.
override getContributionItem method. Inside that use:     org.eclipse.ui.workbench.ContributionItemFactory.REOPEN_EDITORS.create(window)

which will return contribution item. Put it in an array and add this class to dynamic under menu contributions.